# Show output but hide code when sending Rmd to other people?

Tags: output, r-markdown

I have a problem with Rmarkdown when teaching. How can I send file .Rmd to other people without code but output remains?

In python (jupyter notebook, gg collab), I write code and run. After that, I delete the code and send the notebook to other people. They can't see code, but they know the output. Their mission is to write code to have the results as mine.

Is there any platform in R for designing exercises (hide code but show output)?

Thank you for all your advice.

Comment: I already answered your question, but after re-reading, I see you are talking about the .Rmd file, you could render the .Rmd file to HTML, and then send the HTML file with your output, and then delete your R code in the .Rmd file and send them both, 1 with the output, and a template .Rmd

Comment: Maybe I should do that, send the output and template .Rmd. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do with Rstudio and Rmarkdown, I will be creating HTML documents using Rmarkdown and Rstudio.

First, you can specify each R chunk to *hide* the code, this can be done with some chunk options, or easily clicking the preferred option. This is where you can see there is an option to "show output only", no matter the code inside the R chunk.

[image]

Second, you can use the below YAML settings that allow you to render a single HTML document, and allow the end user to select if they want to see the R chunk code, or hide it, while still showing the output.

```
 ---
 title: "Untitled"
 author: "author"
 date: "9/25/2021"
 output:
   html_document:
     code_folding: hide
 ---
```

[image]

Comment: I dont want to knit to PDF, HTML, Word because my student can't write code on these files. I want to send them file .Rmd, but when they open file .Rmd, they only see output not the code.